# Set shortcut to use 3DConnexion SpaceMouse button?

Tags: customization, shortcut, 3d-mouse

How can I setup the right (or left) button on the 3DConnexion's SpaceMouse Wireless to act as <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> keystroke in Blender 2.7x for Mac?

3DConnexion's own SpaceMouse settings don't work.

Comment: It bugs me that this was closed as "off-topic". I need EXACTLY this same problem solved. I cannot find an answer anywhere. gandalf3's answer below doesn't solve the problem. You'd have to create an input mapping (or whatever it's called) for every single context of when one of the buttons is pressed. I personally like one of the buttons mapped to Ctrl+Tab, but I don't want to create a button mapping for every single context that uses Ctrl+Tab. I want to make the button be considered as a Ctrl+Tab by blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the keymap in <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> User preferences > Input*.

To change a shortcut, click the button with the current shortcut and press the new shortcut. Pressing a mouse button works for me:

[image]